# N = No. of ways of distributing 52 balls in 4 Different Containers, in which no box is empty and diff. between 2 boxex is not a multiple of 6. N =?

Tags: permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

Let $N$ be the number of ways of distributing $52$ identical balls into $4$ distinguishable boxes such that no box is empty and the difference between the number of balls in any two of the boxes is not a multiple of $6$. If $N = 100a+b$, where $a,b$ are positive integers less than $100$, find $a+b$.

Thanks in Adv for the Help !

Till now i have tried with ${{n-1}\choose{r-1}} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}$, ( Combination formula ), where $n$ is no of balls and $r$ is the no of boxes,
With this I got $425$ as $N$

But i am unable to get to understand how to change this to adapt the questions imp. points

- $6 \not | $ diff between $2$ box
- $N = 100a+b$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This was a 10 marker on today's IOQM test right? It was one of the toughest papers I think. Anyways, I think the key here is to first consider the residues modulo $6$ and then applying beggar's coin theorem.

Comment: PS I think you mean the difference is not a multiple of 6, as the original question stated.

Comment: @Hersh, yep its the same question, Thanks will edit it

Comment: Can you explain / guide how to get this residue modulo of 6 @Hersh and i didn't get how to apply it on Combinations method.
Thanks !

Comment: Start with $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=52$ and substitute $x_i=1+6k_i+y_i$ with $k_i\ge 0$ and $0\le y_i\le 5$. Find solutions for $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\equiv 0 \pmod 6$ and take it from there.